# Solr exact search with a hyphen

Tags: search, solr, lucene

I am trying to search for a term in Solr in the Title that contains only the string 1604-04. But the results come back with anything that contains 1604 or 04. What would the syntax be to force solr to search on the exact string of 1604-04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use **Classic Tokenizer**.The Classic Tokenizer preserves the same behavior as the Standard Tokenizer with the following exceptions:-

> Words are split at hyphens, unless there is a number in the word, in which case the token is not split and
>   the numbers and hyphen(s) are preserved.

This means if someone searches for 1604-04 then this Tokenizer won't break search string into two tokens.

Answer (score 2):

If you want exact matches only, use a string field or a text field with a KeywordTokenizer as the tokenizer. These will keep your tokens intact as one single entry, and won't break it up into multiple tokens.

The difference is that if you use a Textfield with a KeywordTokenizer, you can still apply other filters, such as a LowercaseFilter, while a string field will store anything verbatim without any further processing possible.

Comment: Thank you so much. It lead us to the correct solution. We actually ended up using the Classic Tokenizer instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your analyzer is splitting "1604-04" into two terms, "1604" and "04". You've received answer on how to change your analysis to stop doing that.

Changing your analysis my not be the best solution (can't be entirely sure based on what you've written). Using a [phrase query](http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_3_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Fields) would be the usual way to do this. You can use a phrase query by wrapping it in quotes:

```
field:"1604-04"
```

This will still analyze and split it into two terms, but it will look for those terms in sequence. So, that query would match "1604-04" and "1604 04", but *not* "1604 some other stuff 04".